# ¿Al copiar un objeto estos quedan sujetos a los mismos cambios?

Tags: variables, object, iframe, objeto

Estoy usando una herramienta que sirve para crear encuestas para usuarios.
La herramienta me genera una pagina (la encuesta) con un objeto JS en el que hay información de la interactuación del usuario con las preguntas y algunas utilidades (métodos) y que ella misma usa para generar preguntas, permitir saltos de pagina, validar, obtener valores de las respuestas, etc...
Por lo tanto, si quiero consultar el valor de algo o ejecutar algún método cuando estoy testándola no tengo mas que dirigirme a la consola y hacerlo.

El problema es que eso solo es posible cuando lanzas la encuesta. Cuando testo la encuesta a través de dicha herramienta, esta lo que hace es insertar dicho resultado final en un iframe. Esto lo hace porque al ser modo test me da ciertas herramientas en un menú que el usuario final no verá.
Entonces acceder a el objeto que mencionaba anteriormente se vuelve mas problemático. Bueno no pasa nada, con window.frames[0] puedo acceder al objeto window del iframe. Así que decido crear un objeto llamado "Clon" en el ámbito del window padre con el objeto window del iframe.

Hasta aquí todo perfecto, esto me está permitiendo consultar y ejecutar metodos con facilidad además de consultar las variables alojadas en el objeto window del iframe, etc. Pero yo creía que al ser una copia si yo modificaba algun valor, alguna propiedad del objeto, esta solo se veria alterada en el clon.
Por ejemplo: Clon.ObjetoDeLaHerramienta.Pregunta4.EleccionUsuario = 5;
Pero para mi sorpresa veo que al modificar el objeto "Clon" también se modifica el objeto iframe.

¿Esto es normal?¿Porque ocurre, porque están enlazados?

Esto realmente no es un inconveniente para mi sino una ventaja pero me surge la curiosidad. Aunque no solo eso, sino que a la vez me preocupa asimilar que están totalmente "vinculadas" y que no sea así y que en el futuro, cuando intente modificar el original mediante el Clon, se produzcan errores que me pasen totalmente desapercibidos debido a esto.

¿Están totalmente vinculados, cualquier modificación que hago en uno se aplica exactamente en el otro?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!! (:

Comment: Estás copiando el objeto, o haciendo una asignación? Te recomiendo leer [esto](http://www.etnassoft.com/2013/10/15/copiando-arrays-y-objetos-en-javascript/)

Comment: Vaya, perfecto!!! Pues sí, lo que estaba haciendo era una asignación. Justamente lo que quería era eso, nombres e información, ese artículo me ha sido de gran ayuda. No es la primera vez que me pasa algo parecido, lo mismo me ocurrió con un array hace tiempo y recuerdo que esa vez sí que fue un inconveniente y me volví loco. Muchísimas gracias!! Como puedo marcar tu respuesta como la mejor?

Comment: Al se un comentario y no una respuesta no es posible. Pero puedes marcar la respuesta de @aferrercrafter que es bastante completa. Me alegro de haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando intentaste copiar los objetos

```
obj1 = obj2
```

Lo que copiaste fue la referencia, no sus valores. Por tanto las dos variables apuntan a la misma instancia del objeto.

```js
var obj1 = {prop : "Valor Original Objeto 1"}
var obj2 = {prop : "Valor Original Objeto 2"}

console.log(obj1.prop)
console.log(obj2.prop)

obj1 = obj2

console.log(obj1.prop)
console.log(obj2.prop)

obj2.prop = "Valor Despues de Copiar"

console.log(obj1.prop)
console.log(obj2.prop)
```

Para "clonar/copiar"  los objetos, tendrías que copiar valor por valor

```
var obj1 = {
    this.prop1  = obj2.prop1,
    this.prop12 = obj2.prop2
    ...
}
```

Para algunos casos simples, también podrías tratar al objeto como un json

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```